# My mac's screen isn't showing. How do I get it to use an external monitor as primary?

Tags: multiple-monitors, macbook

I have a macbook (not pro) with OS X on it. The primary screen is not showing anything.
I've connected a secondary monitor but what step should I take to make that primary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is assuming your graphics card isn't failing: Try using the following key combination `COMMAND + F1` if that doesn't work try `ALT + COMMAND + F1`

This will enable display mirroring. So it will mirror whatever is supposed to be on the main display over to the external display.